# Ubuntu server mnt drive

Tags: server, mount, hard-drive

I currently set up a headless server For plex I'm currently using winSCP to remote into my server and drag and drop files. However, I have a secondary drive that I mounted on the server and I want to drag and drop my media there.

But every time I go to do it, winSCP does not have access. winSCP shows the root files I can drag the files to my main drive, but I cannot drag them to the secondary drive.

What do I need to do to gain access to my mounted drive/secondary drive? I do not use a key when logging in to winSCP. I use my login and password, which I believe gives me sudo access.

I mounted the secondary drive, I formatted it and partitioned it. I also added no notes in the config file so that it mounts the drive on boot, so I know the drive is mounted in terminal.

Can anybody help me? I'm new at this. I don't know if I'm asking the right questions online, or somebody knows a YouTube video that could walk me through this process. Anything would be gratefully appreciated.

Comment: Edit your question to include the complete output of `ls -lah` for both of your mount points.

Comment: I using ubuntu 20.04 LTS server build